# Chevy Cruze 2011 ABS light on

Tags: abs, cruze

The ABS light came on and not go away, then after reaching 20km/h the stability control came on too. Does this will be a risk while driving in summer?. The car seems to work ok in terms of brakes. What do i need to check in order to repair or diagnose the problem by myseft?

Comment: It's not going to be a problem until you need to do a *genuine* emergency stop, and you don't. After that, it still might not be *your* problem if you are dead.

Answer (score 1):

First step is to get the codes read. Then post them back here for more specific advice.